# Pop up window opened from code behind is not getting closed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, client-side

i am opening a pop up from code behind(which i am using as waiting image while processing) after that i am doing some activity in background ,when the  activity is done i am closing that pop up . the problem is after the activity is over the pop is not getting closed. what i am doing wrong, here is my code snippet:-

```
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
            sb.Append("var win=");
            sb.Append("window.open('WaitingImage.aspx', 'Wait',");
            sb.Append("'width=800, height=600, menubar=no, resizable=no');window.focus();<");
            sb.Append("/script>");

            Type t = this.GetType();
            if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(t, "PopupScript"))
            {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(t,"PopupScript", sb.ToString());
            }
        //pop up opened.. now do the processing :-
             uploadFiles();
        //now close the pop up after work is done:-

        System.Text.StringBuilder sbs = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sbs.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
        sbs.Append("window.close()");
        sbs.Append("/script>");
        Type tr = this.GetType();
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(tr, "PopupScript", sbs.ToString());
```

Comment: i think you're calling window.close() in the parent window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign the popup to the win variable, but when you closee you call window.close...

Try to change

```
 sbs.Append("window.close()");
```

to

```
 sbs.Append("win.close()");
```

Comment: @2gDev--when u closed the script tag ,the scope of that variable is no more.....then how it will work???

Comment: <script> var win= .. </script> puts win in global scope.
Also I would do `if (win && !win.closed) win.close();`

Comment: take a look at this line : 
sbs.Append("/script>"); where is the closing script tag?? I've tested on my local machine and it worked!

Comment: @Pranav : it's not true... where do you read this behavior? 
When you declare a variable inside a function that variable is inaccessible outside the function, but in this case win is like a global variable.

Comment: it was due to Key used to register your Client Script .